# What is the best way to send hundreds of API requests and deserialize to objects in an efficient and fast way

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp

My project generates hundreds of requests and each request returns a 3-megabyte JSON file

I created a base class that deals with the requests and returns objects that I need
But it seems. That he does not handle the amount of requests very well

```
protected IErrorLogger _errorLogger;

public BaseClient(IDeserializer serializer, IErrorLogger errorLogger, string baseUrl)
{
    _errorLogger = errorLogger;

    AddHandler("application/json", serializer);
    AddHandler("text/json", serializer);
    AddHandler("text/x-json", serializer);
    BaseUrl = new Uri(baseUrl);
}

public T Get<T>(IRestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    var response = Execute<T>(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return response.Data;
    }
    else
    {
        LogError(BaseUrl, request, response);
        return default(T);
    }
}

public override IRestResponse Execute(IRestRequest request)
{
    var response = base.Execute(request);
    TimeoutCheck(request, response);
    return response;
}
public override IRestResponse<T> Execute<T>(IRestRequest request)
{
    var response = base.Execute<T>(request);
    TimeoutCheck(request, response);
    return response;
}
```

How do you recommend me to play it?

Comment: Increase max http outbound connections limit and make your request async so it will not take much resources to handle plain IO bound load.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Can you bring me reading material or an example? I am in the learning stage and this is a study project